# Android: Eclipse ADT bundle install not working on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm trying to get started developing an android app, and I have a machine running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS to do it on (64 bit). I downloaded the ADT bundle which is simple a zipped
directory tree, and expanded it. I tried running eclipse, but it failed due to some missing libraries, and so (after googling for solutions) I had to install a few 32bit libraries. After this, Eclipse runs, but it is broken in that it doesn't seem to be able to display any external windows. For example when you start it there is a welcome screen with a hyperlink on it which should go to a tutorial "Build your first app". Although the cursor changes when hovering over the link, nothing happens when you click it - or any other link on the page. More seriously, when invoking the emulator, it similarly fails to appear. So it seems that for some reason, it cannot open, or display popup windows.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Eclipse from repo, run

```
sudo eclipse
```

Select Help > Install New Software
Add new repo:

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

Install ADT and restart Eclipse (as root)
After it runs select Use existing SDKs and chose previously unpacked SDK directory

The main problem I had, was no root privileges during install. If you install or update, use always sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the ADT Bundle for Linux on my Ubuntu 13.04, and when I tried to run the "eclipse" application, it either didn't do anything at all when I clicked it or it said that it didn't know how to run executable files, and asked to search the ubuntu software center for a possible application to run it.

What I did was

1. Open Terminal application (Ctrl + Alt + T)
2. Move to the directory by
3. using "cd "  typed "ls" and it showed the contents of folder, with the "eclipse" file as not green, simply white.
4. type "chmod +x eclipse"
5. Double click the "eclipse" file from your file browser.

It should open the cool green-adt eclipse splash screen and start downloading some necessary files.